# How do you add a gradient to the default variable for background color with Less?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

I am trying to change the default variable, @body-bg, in a variables.less file for Bootstrap 3 so that my background is a gradient, but I haven't had much luck.

Referencing from a previously asked question about adding a gradient mixin, my attempt was to write the gradient as a mixin and then assign it to @body-bg in my mixin file, but the compiler threw an error for an 'Unrecognized input' at the line where I wanted to assign the mixin to @body-bg. My code was roughly as follows:

```
@import "../variables.less";
#gradient {
    .vertical(@start-color: #989ca0; @end-color: #234362; @start-percent: 0%; @end-percent: 100%) 
    {
          background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left @start-percent, left @end-percent, from(@start-color), to(@end-color)); // Safari 4+, Chrome 2+
          background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, @start-color @start-percent, @end-color @end-percent); // Safari 5.1+, Chrome 10+
          background-image:  -moz-linear-gradient(top, @start-color @start-percent, @end-color @end-percent); // FF 3.6+
          background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, @start-color @start-percent, @end-color @end-percent); // Standard, IE10
    }
}

body {
    #gradient.vertical(#989ca0; #234362; 0%; 100%);
}
```

Based on the error I got, is it not possible to assign a mixin to a default variable in Less? I noticed that if I only reference #gradient, the code compiles, although the gradient certainly doesn't show.

I've also tried to find what @body-bg would equate to in the .css file, and I think this would be body.background-color, but the following few lines wouldn't add the gradient either:

```
.body.background-color {
    #gradient.vertical(#989ca0; #234362; 0%; 100%);
}
```

I would appreciate any help on this issue, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the important thing to realize is that Less variables usually represent (and used as) a CSS property *value(s)* (though since recent version it is also possible to assign an arbitrary ruleset to a variable too). Now if you look at the way the [`@body-bg` is actually applied to the body](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.2.0/less/scaffolding.less#L32) in Bootstrap sources it becomes obvious you simply can't use a mixin there. In other words, the simplest way to assign a gradient background to the body is to use old good CSS cascading directly, i.e. just:

```css
body {
    #gradient.vertical(#989ca0, #234362, 0%, 100%);
}
```

Comment: It's very curious that I had those exact three lines of code in my question, yet it wasn't working for me yesterday. What I had actually meant to write (which wasn't working) was _@body-bg: #gradient.vertical(#989ca0, #234362, 0%, 100%);_ instead. This works perfectly though, thank you!